# Familiar-looking form for exact differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> We have a function $u(x,y)$ and an equation of the form
>
> $$\mathrm du=(1+2xy^{3})\ \mathrm dx+3x^{2}y^{2}\ \mathrm dy=0.$$
>
> Why is possible to reformulate it to
>
> $$(1+2xy^{3})+3x^{2}y^{2}\ \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=0?$$

In fact we don't know if $y$ is a function of $x$...

Comment: $y$ is usually considered as a function of $x$ in this cases.

Comment: We do know that there is a functional relation between $x$ and $y$, precisely thanks to the differential equation !

Answer (score 1):

The whole subject of solving a differential equation is to find a solution $y=f(x)$ which satisfies the equation.

Thus the assumption of $y=f(x)$ is not unreasonable.
Sometimes it is not  possible to explicitly solve for $y$ as a function of $x$ but it does not mean that the assumption of $y=f(x)$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

An ODE like $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ is exact if $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$. Then its solution is given by
$$\int M(x,y)~ dx \mbox{(treat y as constant)}+\int \mbox{( terms of N not containg x)}~ dy =C.$$

So the solution of your ODE is $$\int (1+2xy^3 dx +\int 0 ~dy=C \Rightarrow x+x^2y^3 =C \Rightarrow y=\left( \frac{C-x}{x^2} \right)^{1/3}= f(x).$$So eventually, here also you get $y=f(x)$ as the solution of your ODE.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to common belief, $dx$ and $d$y are not "infinitesimals" but differentials, i.e. finite numbers (they are the linear part of the functions). This allows to use ordinary algebra.

$$(1+2xy^{3})\ \mathrm dx+3x^{2}y^{2}\ \mathrm dy=0\implies(1+2xy^{3})+3x^{2}y^{2}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=0$$
as well as
$$(1+2xy^{3})\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}+3x^{2}y^{2}=0.$$

And by definition,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y'(x).$$